# Prevent SASS/Compass From Outputting Partials

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am successfully using Compass to generate a CSS file but it is also outputting my partials to the CSS directory. How can I make it only output the stylesheets that will be used in the page? There's no need to add the partials to the destination css directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:

> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don’t want
>   to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning
>   of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS
>   file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials

Comment: I thought that was the case but I DO have underscores at the beginning and they're still being compiled. Odd.

Comment: It turns out that the PHPStorm File Watcher was the problem. It was compiling anything with a .scss file extension.

Comment: Yeah, my Atom sass compile-on-save plugin is doing the same @voidstate